# SQL calculation for finding time difference

Tags: mysql, sql, time, date-arithmetic

I have used the (NOW) function to get the current `TIME` and insert into database as "Arrival Time."

This is shown below:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Time(Arrival_Time)
VALUES(NOW())";
```

The type is time and inserts as;

```
12:17:29
```

I need to calculate waiting time by (current time - arrival time);

Example: Current time (13:15) Arrival Time (12:15)

So this would display:

```
Waiting time 
1 hour
```

Here are the solutions Ive tried;

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No connection");
mysqli_select_db($conn, "a&e") or die('Could not select database.');

$query = "SELECT Arrival_time, TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Time";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Waiting Time</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

 echo "<tr>
  <td>" . $row->Waiting_Time . "</td>
  </tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

EDIT

```
$query = "SELECT Arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), Arrival_time)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time FROM Time";";
```

Displaying

```
Waiting time 
3 hours
```

How would I use `time` so that if; waiting_time exceeds 3 hours, alert "This patient must be seen next!".

Comment: So reverse the times to get a positive value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CURRENT_TIME` or `CURTIME()` instead of `NOW()` :

```
SELECT Arrival_time, TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,CURRENT_TIME) as Waiting_Time FROM Time;
```

[EDIT]
Because `NOW()` is a **DATETIME**, it's not just the time. [MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

[ADD]
You can use [TIME_FORMAT(time_diff, '%H hours')](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) to get hours.
And to remove the `-`, add `ABS()` method to get the absolute value :

```
SELECT Arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,CURRENT_TIME)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time FROM Time;
```

[Change return value if timediff > 3]

```
SELECT Arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,CURRENT_TIME)),'%H hours left') as Waiting_Time FROM Time WHERE CAST(TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,CURRENT_TIME)),'%H') as UNSIGNED INTEGER)>3
```

You can make all you want with the timediff value... Here, The query just return rows with a diff greater than 3 hours...

Comment: YES, there is a missing comma... Retry now! (I'd just past your query, without checked it)

Comment: because Arrival time is using NOW() i think its getting messed up. I have use CURRENT TIME, which has worked! but its now displaying --01:13:16

Comment: When I try this query : `SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURTIME() ,CURRENT_TIME) as Waiting_Time` it works. But this one `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW() ,CURRENT_TIME) as Waiting_Time` don't. I think it's just optimized to use CURRENT_TIME to compare with another TIME... isn't it?

Comment: @SF For more explanation, when you use `NOW()` in the INSERT query, the database make a **cast** to retrieve the TIME part of the  TIMESTAMP so in the table, you only get TIME. But when you wan't to compare a time, you will use CURRENT_TIME to directly get a TIME type.

Comment: I shall update the question to show you what I have implemented and what it is displaying.

Comment: Not sure why, but SELECT Arrival_time, TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,CURRENT_TIME)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time FROM Time; isnt working?

Comment: Can you put the `Arrival_time` when it doesn't work? I'd just tried `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(ABS(TIMEDIFF('10:10:10',CURRENT_TIME)),'%H hours') as Waiting_Time;` and it works fine...

Comment: I got it working. How would I use this function to alert if the time exceeds a certain value; for example; 3 hours?

Comment: Thankyou but i just need a simple function to alert; so if the time is > 3 hours; then alert "patient needs to be seen next."

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma in your SQL statement, between the selected fields.
You're comparing a timestamp ( string) with a date. You need to cast your string back to date.

Change this

```
SELECT Arrival_time TIMEDIFF(Arrival_time,NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Time
```

To

```
SELECT Arrival_time, TIMEDIFF(DATETIME(Arrival_time),NOW()) as Waiting_Time FROM Time
```

Comment: @SF you also need to cast your time stamp to a date. Updated.

Comment: I haven't used TIMESTAMP, it is inserting as TIME into the Arrival_Time table. Do i need to implement this?

Comment: @SF you said "I have used the (NOW) function". This function _Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context._ refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now. In other words, it's a timestamp :-). Cast it back to DATE.

Comment: I am using NOW to INSERT the TIME into the table, but this INSERTS as 11:16:21 (no date, just time.) This is all very confusing

Comment: awesome, thanks so much for your help, i reversed arrival time and currtime to get a positive time. Thanks!